# Best way to encrypt data using php - I am not sure if I doing it correctly

Tags: encryption, php, md5

I want to encrypt some data within my php file when I add the stuff to my mysql database.

This is how I do it.

I create a static key like:

```
$key = md5("pass");
```

Then I have two functions called encrypt() and decrypt() and they do this:

```
function encrypt($string, $key){
    $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
    return $string;
}

function decrypt($string, $key){
    $string = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    return $string;
}
```

I am not sure if this is best practice but like how do I generate a key other than md5?

Comment: Is there a reason by design that you can't randomly generate a key, or do you have to use a password?

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two problems with this approach.

1. Your choice of key generation
2. Your choice of encryption *mode*

### Key Generation

You're doing `md5("static password")` as your key. This is really bad. First, you're "only" getting 128-bits from MD5 and you're using 256-bit keyed AES, thereby wasting cycles (because AES-256 is slower than AES-128) on something you're not using anyways. Secondly, you password is weak. `"pass"` is **not** a secure password and I really hope you replace it with something *much* stronger for production use. Third, you're using *plain MD5* for the password processing ([also see our canonical answer on password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/71460)). This is as bad as it can get, because the ciphertexts could be attacked using precomputed (rainbow) tables and MD5 is a fast hashing function, allowing fast brute-forcing of your password. Fourth: **Why are you even using a password!?**. There's no logical reason to use a static (human-readable) password instead of **a secure, randomly generated key** of the desired size. This way you don't have to worry about brute-force, you don't have to worry about using MD5 (which will give bad press) you don't have to worry about your key to be too short.

### Encryption mode

While you use AES-256 as encryption algorithm (which is OK), you're using [**ECB**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#ECB) as your mode of operation for AES. This way you have two problems: a) you're leaking which AES blocks (16-bytes) are equal and b) you have to pad your messages to be a multiple of 16-bytes. To fix these problems you need to swithc the mode. [**GCM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#ECB) is the best option you have. Unfortunaly, this isn't properly supported by PHP [until PHP 7.1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/openssl_aead) via `openssl_encrypt()` or `mcrypt_encrypt()` (which you really shouldn't use, because it's slower, no longer maintained and less hardened than OpenSSL). If you already have PHP 7.1, then fine, you can use AES-GCM with `openssl_encrypt()`, which will protect your ciphertext from being read and / or modified, provided you hand a unique (not secret) nonce over for each encryption. Until you have proper PHP 7.1 [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) encryption, you have to use an ad-hoc construction. This means, you first encrypt the data using a (random) 16-byte [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) with [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode and then you calculate the [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)-[SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA256) of the ciphertext and store the resulting tag, so you can verify it upon next read access.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your kind comments. Firstly, I am not encrypting a password - but the actual data in the database such as the customers bank card details. I want to ideally encrypt that and then decrypt it#

Comment: @BenjMikesozery, when talking about passwords and their processing, I was specifically referring to your `$key = md5("pass");` and not to the bulk data that you're encrypting using this key. The bulk data (your database contents secured by the *secure* key) should of course be reversibly encrypted (i.e. using GCM or CTR+HMAC).

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The only real question I have is, how do I securely encrypt and decrypt the data? Apologies, I am new to web development and security in general

Comment: @BenjMikesozery, [the linked question by Xander](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/80888/71460) does a really good job and NaCl / libsodium is really easy to use normally and should allow you to get the data encrypted securely, easily.

Comment: is openssl_encrypt() safe and any good?

Comment: @BenjMikesozery, libsodium should be safer to use (because it apparently already has an AEAD interface), but `openssl_encrypt()` will do the job if used properly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response - I am leaning more towards openssl_encrypt(). Is it easy to use?

Comment: @BenjMikesozery follow the advice given here (use openssl_encrypt() with AEAD directly or paired with HMAC) and you'll be fine. If you do this (and use a strong key), chances are, you won't screw up.

Comment: The question is, how do I do this? Are there any tutorials online?